# Открытие PDF-файлов при помощи моего приложения

Tags: android, intellij-idea, pdf

В моем приложении реализовано открытие PDF-документов, но это не основной функционал программы, а вторичный. Хотелось бы добавить его в список приложений, которые могут открывать PDF. Как это сделать и как обработать открытие файла?

Файл, который пользователь хочет открыть в проводнике. Если выбрано приложение по умолчанию для данного типа файла, то он откроется при помощи него, если не задано, то откроется список с приложениями на выбор. Вот в этот список и нужно добавить мое приложение.

Comment: что вы вкладываете в понятие открыть файл?

Comment: Файл, который пользователь хочет открыть в проводнике. Если выбрано приложение по умолчанию для данного типа файла, то он откроется при помощи него, если не задано, то откроется список с приложениями на выбор. Вот в этот список и нужно добавить мое приложение

Comment: добавьте эту информацию в вопрос